# How to uninstall BOOST 1.49 and install BOOST 1.54 in ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, wget, c++, boost

I have a boost 1.49 in my ubuntu system. And I am trying to uninstall boost 1.49 and completely remove it from my system.

And after that install the `Boost 1.54.0`

I did like this to uninstall 1.49 from my system -

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-dev
sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-all-dev
```

And after that when I do below command to see the version, it still says I have 1.49

```
cat /usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"
//  BOOST_LIB_VERSION must be defined to be the same as BOOST_VERSION
#define BOOST_LIB_VERSION "1_49"
```

Not sure why?

And I tried installing Boost 1.54.0 version like this -

```
wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.54.0/boost_1_54_0.tar.gz/download
tar -xvzf boost_1_54_0.tar.gz
cd boost_1_54_0/
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=atomic,date_time,exception,filesystem,iostreams,locale,program_options,regex,signals,system,test,thread,timer,log
sudo ./b2 install
```

But still it is not showing me boost 1.54.0 version installed?

Any pointers how to remove BOOST 1.49 from my system and install BOOST 1.54 in my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation of Boost via apt installs several Boost packages which are not uninstalled on the `remove` that you are using. Try `sudo apt-get autoremove` which will remove the non-required packages. I tested this on my Ubuntu 12.04.x LTS which successfully removed the non-required Boost packages.

The way you are reinstalling the package might install Boost on your (/home) as opposed to on system (/usr..).

Use the `--prefix` option of `b2` to set the installation location.

Depending on where it installs, at the completion of `./b2`, you will see messages like these:

```
The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

/home/you/boost_1_54_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

/home/you/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib
```

So, update the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `C_INCLUDE_PATH` accordingly for further usages of Boost.

Comment: Thanks Ketan. And after that how do I install BOOST 1.54.0? The way I am doing is correct?

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer.